# Class AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate is implemented in both framework and project,One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, frame

I have created framework and using pods pod 'AFNetworking' and same pods used in project also given warning how can i resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

use use_frameworks! in your framework's pod file and you are done.